# Calling DC.flush_all clears the whole cache, also when using Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, passenger, dalli

I am using Phusion passenger and memcached (Dalli Gem).  I want to clear the complete cache (similar to running telnet localhost 11211  and then running flush_all on the telnet command).

Is it save to run:

```
DC.flush_all
```

in a forked Phusion passenger setup?

Answer (score 0):

What about calling `Rails.cache.clear`?